# How to set two ajax event for one click action  in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

i have to implement a scenerio Like  To change an image and display Text correspondingly. means two ajax at same time ...  so i am writing a code like this but image is changing and it is working but Text is not displaying .
TEXT is coming after refresh of that page i.e Text is replaced but it is not displaying .....
**Code is:**

```
<h:commandLink class="SampleImageCSS">
            <h:graphicImage id="sample2" alt="No iamge to display"
                value="#{carDetails.carUrl2}" height="100" width="100"
                title="Car For Beeding" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{carDetails.rootImage}"
                value="#{carDetails.carUrl2}" />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{carDetails.view}" 
                value="#{carDetails.viewDetails['carUrl2']}" />
            <f:ajax event="action" render="rootImage">
            </f:ajax>
            <f:ajax event="action" render="ViewId">
            </f:ajax>
        </h:commandLink>
```

how to fire ajax request to do two job at same time ??
Manged Bean:

```
public class CarDetails {

  private int id;
  private String carUrl1;
  private String carUrl2;
  private String carUrl3;
  private String carUrl4;
  private String carUrl5;
  private String carUrl6;
  private String view;
  public String getView() {
    return view;
}
public void setView(String view) {
    this.view = view;
}
  HashMap<String, String> viewDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();

  public HashMap<String, String> getViewDetails() {
    return viewDetails;
}
public void setViewDetails(HashMap<String, String> viewDetails) {
    this.viewDetails = viewDetails;
}
//other getter setter
public CarDetails(){
  carUrl1="http://www.screamingtiger.com/images/car1.jpg";
  carUrl2="http://www.allbestwallpapers.com/tagwallpaper/convertible%20car-wallpapers.jpg";
  carUrl3="http://media.treehugger.com/assets/images/2011/10/ec-rnd-005.jpg";
  carUrl4="http://www.urbadriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/car.jpg";
  carUrl5="http://www.businessfinancemag.info/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/car_loans.jpg";
  carUrl6="http://cars-wallpapers.eu/images/Old_cars/00000018.jpg";
  rootImage="http://www.screamingtiger.com/images/car1.jpg";

  viewDetails.put("carUrl1", "Front view");
  viewDetails.put("carUrl2", "Right Side View");
  viewDetails.put("carUrl3", "Top or Plan View");
  viewDetails.put("carUrl4", "Rear view");
  viewDetails.put("carUrl5", "Back view");
  viewDetails.put("carUrl6", "Bottom View");}}
```

Comment: Could you please post the corresponding JSF `ManagedBean`?

Comment: Solved it by writing code like "<f:ajax event="action" render="rootImage ViewId">" instead of two separate ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

simple one after some google got it ...

Solved it by writing code like `<f:ajax event="action" render="rootImage ViewId">` instead of two separate ajax request.